# How can you check a website which is getting stuck while loading?

Tags: javascript, web, page-load-time

My website www.travellerkids.com is getting stuck while loading. I think its a javascript issue, but I dont know.
It loads properly if I refresh.
What tools can I use to debug.

Comment: You could try Firebug, which is included with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug (extension) in Firefox or developer tools (ctrl+shift+i) in chrome. These are the tools you should use to debug.

Answer (score 1):

chrome javascript console.  CTRL shift J on Windows.

this will be your absolute best bet at getting an idea of what's going on.